# The Numbers Aren't Adding Up

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a piece where it adds up information for the customer. Here's my code:

```
lovely_loveseat_description = """Lovely Loveseat. Tufted polyester blend on wood. 
32 inches high x 40 inches wide x 30 inches deep. Red or white."""

#We're creating the price for the loveseat

lovely_loveseat_price = 254.00
lovely_loveseat_price = str(254.00)


#Making a new variable

stylish_settee_description = """Stylish Settee. Faux leather on birch. 
29.50 inches high x 54.75 inches wide x 28 inches deep. Black."""
stylish_settee_price = 180.50
stylish_settee_price = str(180.50)

#Making the 3rd and final variable

luxurious_lamp_description = """"Luxurious Lamp. Glass and iron. 36 inches tall. Brown with cream shade."""
luxurious_lamp_price = 52.15
luxurious_lamp_price = str(52.15)

#We're adding sales tax as another variable
sales_tax = .088
customer_one_total = 0
customer_one_itemization = " "
customer_one_itemization += lovely_loveseat_price
customer_one_itemization += luxurious_lamp_price
customer_one_tax = customer_one_total * sales_tax
customer_one_tax += customer_one_total

print("Customer One Items:")
print(str(customer_one_itemization))
print("Customer One Total:")
print(customer_one_total)
```

The output is not even remotely correctly, and I'm not sure why. I'm new to programming. Here's the output:

```
Customer One Items:
 254.052.15
Customer One Total:
0
```

How is it even coming up with that?

Comment: You appear to be adding strings, not numbers.  For example: `"one" + "two"` equals `"onetwo"`

Comment: you are typecasting numbers into strings. '2' is not 2. `2 + 2 = 4 ` and  `'2' + '2' = '22'`

Comment: You seem to have mixed up `tax` and `total`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `customer_one_total` is correct, you haven't changed that from when you set it to `0` with `customer_one_total = 0`

And it outputs the `254.052.15` because you turned them all to strings, without keeping them as integers. Try getting rid of the `str()` around each furniture variable.

I've fixed your code, and just as a side note good luck with your programming! It can get tough sometimes, but stick with it!

```
lovely_loveseat_description = """Lovely Loveseat. Tufted polyester blend on wood. 
32 inches high x 40 inches wide x 30 inches deep. Red or white."""

#We're creating the price for the loveseat

lovely_loveseat_price = 254.00


#Making a new variable

stylish_settee_description = """Stylish Settee. Faux leather on birch. 
29.50 inches high x 54.75 inches wide x 28 inches deep. Black."""
stylish_settee_price = 180.50

#Making the 3rd and final variable

luxurious_lamp_description = """"Luxurious Lamp. Glass and iron. 36 inches tall. Brown with cream shade."""
luxurious_lamp_price = 52.15

#We're adding sales tax as another variable
sales_tax = .088
customer_one_total = 0
customer_one_itemization += lovely_loveseat_price
customer_one_itemization += luxurious_lamp_price
customer_one_tax = customer_one_total * sales_tax
customer_one_total += customer_one_tax

print("Customer One Items:")
print(customer_one_itemization)
print("Customer One Total:")
print(customer_one_total)
```

If this helps, can you make sure to accept it so any others with the same problem can find it!